# What is the proper way of accessing a MariaDB database inside a Dockercontainer from a non docker app?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mariadb

I have a mariadb database within a docker container, and I want to use it to store the data of my nextcloud instance running natively on the same machine.
I can access the database with the default docker ip, `172.18.0.2`, but something in my mind tells me there has to be a better way.

This is the configuration I'm using for the database container

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:
  mariadb:
    container_name: maria_database
    image: mariadb
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "password"
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/mariadb:/var/lib/mysql
      - /var/log/mariadb:/var/log/mysql  
    command:
      - --character-set-server=utf8mb4
      - --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
    restart: unless-stopped
```

Comment: `3306:3306` actually means "bind port 3306 on any IP on the docker host (i.e. your OS) to port 3306 in the container". You can use the docker bridge as you did but its IP might change from one system to an other. Simply use `localhost:3306` which will never move.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are port-forwarding MariaDB port to your machine port.
So, you should be able to access the DB by using `localhost:3306` from your nextcloud instance.